# Keeping divs in shape

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few issues that I can't really get.

a. If I do something like:

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
```

Scrollsbars in my browser will appear. How to avoid that? I want my top bar to be full width, with padded content but I don't want it to exceed real width and make scrollbars appear. How to do that?

b. Do you have any articles on how to scale website elements according to user's resolution? When I try it with

```
    position: absolute;
    top: (some percentage)%
    left: (some percentage)%
```

It's never accurate. With pixels instead of percents - it's not accurate either for different resolutions.

c. Menu overlay

Is there any way to level divs so that my drop-down css-only menu doesn't appear BEHIND divs ? When that happens, I can't click on certain items in that menu because they hide behind a body div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't ask multiple things in one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. add `box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box` to your code. It will make the padding be within the 100% width, check [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for more info and here for a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNXx8/)

b. try searching the web for responsive designs. Plenty to find about how to display your website based on different devices. You probably don't want to scale everything.

c. are you looking for [z-index](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)? Can't help you any more than that with the information you give. Add your HTML/CSS code if you need to know more.

Comment: This answer should get three points for answering all of your questions. Normally, your question would not be answered because you do not show what you've tried for everything, rather you are asking for concepts.

Answer (score 1):

All of your issues are solved with plain ole CSS, so that's good news!

**Padding**

This is because of the way CSS handles padding. So for instance if you set your element to be:

```
#id{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   padding:10px; 
}
```

It would actually end up being 120px x 120px . This is explained here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html.

You can solve this by using the box-sizing method detailed here http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

**Scaling depending on Resolution**

This is called responsive design. It's really too much to cover here but the basics is that you use media queries to do this. That is detailed here http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

**Menu Overlay**

You can solve this with the z-index property given to you by CSS. That works essentially like this: z-index:1 is below z-index:2. The caveat is that z-index will only work if a position is declared on your element.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Again, no js is needed here and that's great news because CSS will be much faster for you and much more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

### a)

of course scrollbars will appear because you have a with of 100% + 10px

what you can do is:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 90%;
padding: 10px; // if screen allows it
```

### b)

to scale pages acording to resolution I highly recommend you bootstrap it is really easy and really fast to make your page multidevice http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the attribute:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/se34t/1/ This allows the padding to be calculated within the 100% width.